# Cannot make mysql database connection from php

Tags: php, mysql

I am not being able to make database connection from php. I'm getting HTTP 500 Internal Server Error while making database connection.
[Error Log on /var/log/nginx/error.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ox2F1.png)

my php code go like this:

[image]

Error log on nginx:
thrown in /var/www/php/projects/loginsys/partials/_dbConnect.php on line 6" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: php, request: "GET /projects/loginsys/partials/_dbConnect.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: "php"

Comment: First of all, please go read [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Check if you can connect via console, i.e. run `mysql -h localhost -u shudarsan -p`. Maybe there is something with the database, not PHP. But yes, please provide the error in text and it would be much better to see the full error

Comment: Yes, I can make connection from console.

Comment: Your password is the full MySQL username? 

Comment: @matigo The password is correct.